# Finding the location of a database created in phpmyadmin in my Pc

Tags: php

I've created a database in phpmyadmin and I want this database to copy into a USB flash but I can'find its location.Can someone tell me whwere the databases created by phpmyadmin are stored into our pc? Thanks

Comment: It's depends of your MySQL config, not a phpMyAdmin question. What's your goal? You can export the database from phpMyAdmin interface.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need to know its location, what you need is dump the result.

What you do is:

1. go to `phpmyadmin`
2. choose the `database` needed
3. go to the `Export tab` on the top of the page
4. choose your format (in your case `SQL`)
5. and you click on `Go`, the necessary SQL database structure with its data would be downloaded for you